# How to adjust the border of one figure in a standalone document with many figures?

Tags: pstricks, standalone

I currently have a `standalone` class document in which I have a few `tikz` and `ps` pictures, one after the other. As expected, this `.tex` files generates a pdf with a `stanalone` figure for each of my tikz figures. As it can be seen in the output, I need to change the `standalone` border only for the second figure (not the first one). Can I do such a thing?

```
\documentclass[tikz,pstricks]{standalone}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{pst-3d, tikz-3dplot} % To draw in 3D.
\usepackage{pgfplots} % To draw plots.
\usepackage{pst-all} % To get egameps to work
\usepackage{egameps} % To draw simple plots

% TIKZ & PGFPLOTS LIBRARIES & SETTINGS

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns}
        
% FIGURES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

% Figure 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=1]
\def\laxis{5}
\def\ltriangle{3}
\begin{scope}[-latex]
\draw (0,0,0) -- (\laxis,0,0) node [left] {$x$};
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,\laxis,0) node [right] {$y$};
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\laxis) node [above] {$z$};
\end{scope}
\filldraw [opacity=.3] (\ltriangle,0,0) -- (0,\ltriangle,0) --
(0,0,\ltriangle) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

% Figure 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\psset{unit=0.1mm}
\begin{pspicture}(85,-25)(765,250)
\putbranch(300,240)(2,1){200}
\egalhshift=0
\iib{}{$p_1$}{$p_2$}[c][$1$][]
\putbranch(500,140)(2,1){250}
\egalhshift=0
\iiib{}{$0.1$}{$0.89$}{$0.01$}[c][$5$][$1$][$0$]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: try to put this before the second picture: `\setkeys{standalone.cls}{border=5mm 10mm 2mm 6mm}` And of course adjust the values according to your needs

Comment: Thank you: your suggestion did the trick! Would you mind writing your comment as answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: The solution in the answer is probably more correct or maybe more user-friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code placed before the second picture should be for you:

```
\standaloneconfig{border=2mm 3mm 4mm 5mm}
```